# File encryption that prevents automated decryption

Tags: aes, 7zip

I use 7zip sometimes to encrypt files. But even the longest passwords can be cracked if someone would try hard enough, just let a machine try all options untill success. 7zip does not seem to prevent this, as seems to me but I'm no expert.
1. Would it be possible to prevent endless tries on an encrypted file
2. Does it exist
3. would I be able to send a file encrypted like this, for example by mail

Comment: Definitely no. File is just constant sequence of bytes. You cannot prevent doing something with it.

Comment: But if you would need a certain programme to decrypt the file. The software could  slow down the proces by blocking after three tries.Other programmes seem to do this on Log In procedures, but it might be a false appearance of the security

Comment: Other program which do this are on another PCs and user cannot control them. Nothing can stop me by install your program on Virtual Machine, try 3 passwords, and then restore VM from saved state before entering passwords.